# Not a class or struct name _D3DCOLORVALUE

Tags: c++, struct, directx

'm coding a image viewer and converter. _D3DCOLORVALUE is defined in d3d8types.h file. I'm using DirectX 8 SDK. If I define a struct with _D3DCOLORVALUE occurred some errors like this :

```
1. error C2504: '_D3DCOLORVALUE' : base class undefined
2. error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_D3DCOLORVALUE'
3. _D3DCOLORVALUE not a class or struct name
```

What could be problem?

Note : this project perfectly working on VB6 but I tried build it on VS2012

My3DStruct.h

```
#include "d3d8types.h"

struct __ColorValue : public _D3DCOLORVALUE //problem is here
{
public:
    void operator = (const D3DCOLORVALUE& cv) { r = cv.r; g = cv.g; b = cv.b; a = cv.a; }
    void operator = (D3DCOLOR cr) { r = ((cr & 0x00ff0000)>>16)/255.0f; g = ((cr & 0x0000ff00)>>8)/255.0f; b = (cr & 0x000000ff)/255.0f; a = ((cr & 0xff000000) >> 24)/255.0f; }
    void Set(float r2, float g2, float b2, float a2) { r = r2; g = g2; b = b2; a = a2; }

    D3DCOLOR ToD3DCOLOR() { return  (((DWORD)(a*255.0f))<<24) | (((DWORD)(r*255.0f))<<16) | (((DWORD)(g*255.0f))<<8) | (((DWORD)(b*255.0f))); }

    __ColorValue() {}
    __ColorValue(D3DCOLOR cr) { *this = cr; }
    __ColorValue(float r2, float g2, float b2, float a2) { this->Set(r2, g2, b2, a2); }

    void operator += (float fDelta) { r += fDelta; g += fDelta; b += fDelta; a += fDelta; }
    void operator -= (float fDelta) { r -= fDelta; g -= fDelta; b -= fDelta; a -= fDelta; }
    void operator *= (float fDelta) { r *= fDelta; g *= fDelta; b *= fDelta; a *= fDelta; }
    void operator /= (float fDelta) { if(0 == fDelta) return; r /= fDelta; g /= fDelta; b /= fDelta; a /= fDelta; }

    D3DCOLORVALUE operator + (float fDelta) { __ColorValue cv = *this; cv.r += fDelta; cv.g += fDelta; cv.b += fDelta; cv.a += fDelta; return cv; }
    D3DCOLORVALUE operator - (float fDelta) { __ColorValue cv = *this; cv.r -= fDelta; cv.g -= fDelta; cv.b -= fDelta; cv.a -= fDelta; return cv; }
    D3DCOLORVALUE operator * (float fDelta) { __ColorValue cv = *this; cv.r *= fDelta; cv.g *= fDelta; cv.b *= fDelta; cv.a *= fDelta; return cv; }
    D3DCOLORVALUE operator / (float fDelta) { __ColorValue cv = *this; cv.r /= fDelta; cv.g /= fDelta; cv.b /= fDelta; cv.a /= fDelta; return cv; }

    void operator += (const D3DCOLORVALUE& cv) { r += cv.r; g += cv.g; b += cv.b; a += cv.a; }
    void operator -= (const D3DCOLORVALUE& cv) { r -= cv.r; g -= cv.g; b -= cv.b; a -= cv.a; }
    void operator *= (const D3DCOLORVALUE& cv) { r *= cv.r; g *= cv.g; b *= cv.b; a *= cv.a; }
    void operator /= (const D3DCOLORVALUE& cv) { r /= cv.r; g /= cv.g; b /= cv.b; a /= cv.a; }

    D3DCOLORVALUE operator + (const D3DCOLORVALUE& cv) { __ColorValue cv2(cv.r, cv.g, cv.b, cv.a); cv2 += cv; return cv2; }
    D3DCOLORVALUE operator - (const D3DCOLORVALUE& cv) { __ColorValue cv2(cv.r, cv.g, cv.b, cv.a); cv2 -= cv; return cv2; }
    D3DCOLORVALUE operator * (const D3DCOLORVALUE& cv) { __ColorValue cv2(cv.r, cv.g, cv.b, cv.a); cv2 *= cv; return cv2; }
    D3DCOLORVALUE operator / (const D3DCOLORVALUE& cv) { __ColorValue cv2(cv.r, cv.g, cv.b, cv.a); cv2 /= cv; return cv2; }
};
```

d3d8types.h

```
#ifndef D3DCOLORVALUE_DEFINED
typedef struct _D3DCOLORVALUE {
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
    float a;
} D3DCOLORVALUE;
#define D3DCOLORVALUE_DEFINED
#endif
```

Comment: The old C style `typedef struct _X {...} X;` is at least ugly in C++ and maybe a problem.  Try `struct _X {...}; typedef _X X;` or go all the way to real C++ style by having only one of the two names.

Comment: @JSF I tried this way but its didn't solved my problem

Comment: Maybe `D3DCOLORVALUE_DEFINED` was defined before including the header? By the way, `__ColorValue` is not a legal user defined identifier because it starts with two underscores.

Comment: thought it and tried like this but not solved again 

`typedef struct _D3DCOLORVALUE {
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
    float a;
} D3DCOLORVALUE;
#ifndef D3DCOLORVALUE_DEFINED
#define D3DCOLORVALUE_DEFINED
#endif`

Comment: Either 1) there is some macro that skips the definition in the header or 2) the header doesn't actually contain what you think it does or 3) the code that you compile doesn't contain what you think it does or 4) your compiler doesn't comply to the standard. Your code [compiles fine in clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da4d78e18803f752)

Comment: to expand what user2079303 said - sometimes your IDE will see the file that you want it to see but the actual compiler will include the wrong one. Try finding the actual file in the directx sdk and add a full path for the #include. If that resolves the issue you need to fix your project settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All identifiers beginning with two underscores (`__`) are [reserved in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers); you should never use them for your own code anywhere.

You should use `D3DCOLORVALUE` instead of `_D3DCOLORVALUE`.  The DirectX 8 SDK is pretty old now, but since you're using that old version you can look at my free book [The Direct3D Graphics Pipeline](https://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/the-direct3d-graphics-pipeline/) that is a mix of DirectX 8/9.  Even with the mix in there, that material should be useful to you when using this old a version of DirectX.  [Chapter 1](http://user.xmission.com/~legalize/book/download/01-Introduction.pdf) discusses `D3DCOLOR` and `D3DCOLORVALUE`.  Are you using DirectX 8 because you're converting VB6 code and Direct3D 8 was the last API exposed to VB?  You're probably better off using Direct3D 9 when doing the port.  Direct3D 10, 11 and 12 are significantly different from 9, but 9 is mostly similar to 8 and 8.1.

The idiom `typedef struct _X X;` is a C-ism because C doesn't recognize the name of a structure as a complete type.  In C you have to write `struct X` all over the place, hence the common idiom to introduce the real structure as the name `_X` and introduce `X` as a synonym for `struct _X` with `typedef`.  All of this is harmless in C++, but also completely unnecessary.  In C++, saying `struct X` means you can use `X` as the type wherever you need it without forcing you to write `struct X` or use a `typedef`.

It looks like you're just trying to provide syntactic sugar for manipulating color values by creating `operator+` members on your `ColorValue` structure.  You don't need to derive from `D3DCOLORVALUE` in order to achieve this; simply define the operators as free functions with appropriate types:

```
inline D3DCOLORVALUE &operator+(D3DCOLORVALUE &lhs, float delta)
{
    lhs.r += delta;
    lhs.g += delta;
    lhs.b += delta;
    lhs.a += delta;
    return lhs;
}
```

I believe Microsoft themselves introduced such free functions or member functions on the structures into the SDK at some point.  I don't recall which version introduced that, but it was probably after DirectX 8.

Finally, it is generally not a good idea to write your own classes that derive from [value types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type) like `D3DCOLORVALUE`.  These are simple structures that don't have virtual destructors and deriving from them leaves you susceptible to [object slicing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).  I recommend instead that you [prefer aggregation over inheritance](http://www.netobjectives.com/competencies/favor-aggregation-over-inheritance).

If your only motivation was to get nice `operator+` behavior on `D3DCOLORVALUE` values, then I suggest the free function approach instead of derivation.